# Link billing account of another project owner

Tags: firebase

I've built an app and used Firebase for hosting and storage. I'd like the production costs to be supported by someone else, so I invited them as a owner to the project. How can we link the Firebase project to their billing account? Do they just have to click on `Modify plan` in the Usage and Billing section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Firebase console the only way to change the billing owner would be to downgrade back to the free plan, and then have the new billing owner upgrade again.

Since any Firebase project is a Cloud project however, you can go into the [Cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/billing) too and change the billing account for the project there by clicking on the overflow <kbd>Actions</kbd> menu of the project and selecting <kbd>Change billing</kbd>:
[image]

Comment: so if right now it's on Free, it's just a matter of the owner of the billing account clicking Upgrade in the Firebase console, right?
Btw, I don't want to ask the other person for their payment details.  Not sure how  I can switch to a billing account that I don't own in google cloud...

Comment: Ah, I missed that the project is currently on the free plan. In that case the billing user can indeed simply click the Upgrade button in the Firebase console

Comment: @EightRice Were you able to set the correct billing owner on your project?

Comment: It'll be another week or so until I ask them to do it. I'll follow up here if there are any issues. Just wanted to make sure that I'm suggesting the right action to the other project stakeholder